# Java why does upcasted object call parent's method implementation?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I encountered an issue while playing around with Java class inheritance, where subclass C has a method fun() like its parent A, but different signature. However I do not understand why the parent class's method is called when fun() is invoked on object x. I do understand that because signature is different this is not exactly method overriding, but i still do not understand why A's fun() method is invoked here.

class A

```
class A{
    public void fun(double d){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

class C

```
public class C extends A{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A x = new C();
        x.fun(6); //prints "A"
    }
    public void fun(int i){
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you yourself explicitely said that x is of type A. If I say String x = "1" and String y = "2", I shouldn't be surprised when x+y = 12

Comment: I thought that Java uses object type to invoke the method instead of the reference type, or was I wrong with that?

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept! And note: theoretically, the compiler *could* understand that in this example x has a different type, but the java language and its tools are designed to prefer "robust simplicity" over anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here:

```
A x = new C();
```

The compiler only remembers: x is of class A.
So when you do:

```
x.fun(6); //prints "A"
```

it looks up the methods that exist in A. There is only one named `fun()`, and that one is taking a double. So the compiler puts *method call to `fun(double)`* into the bytecode. The fact that later, at runtime, x also has a method taking an int doesn't matter. Because at compile time, `fun(double)` was "pinned" so to say.

If you want to get to the polymorphic experience, change the type of `foo()` in C to *also* take double, so: make it a **true** override. Or change the definition to `C x = ...`. Then it will print "C".

That is all there is to this.

Comment: And to hammer the point home, if C also had a second method called `fooBar()`, you wouldn't expect to be able to call it on an instance of A, even if the concrete class is a C. Just because the two `fun()` methods have the same name doesn't mean they're the same method.